# AutoIt Error on Startup after Installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-error-reporting, autoit

Right after I installed windows 10 on a 1 year old Acer laptop that had windows 8.1 I got the following message on startup.  The messages keep multiplying (shown in photo).  I can't seem to find a specific solution for the error "bxblhl." Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Process Explorer showed this as the result when i put the crosshairs onto the error message:

[image]

Comment: +1 for true screenshots :) Do you have any autorun macros in your macro file? It looks like you do. One of them can be crashing. Could you please disable them and [edit] your question what happens after you disabled them?

Comment: Could you please try one more thing? Exit AutoIt completely and launch it **as administrator**. Does this solve the problem?

Comment: @miroxlav thanks for your comments.  i just have a few questions. how do i disable macros? and how can i exit and relauch AutoIt?

Comment: Exit can be done through icon in notification area. Also, "bxblhl" is connected to computer virus/malware (see Google...). Please give your computer scans to understand whether it is not infected. Why do you need AutoIt? Do you often program new macros or do you use it only for some simple task or two? In the latter case, perhaps you can replace it with AutoHotKey.

Comment: @miroxlav thanks. i have no idea what AutoIt even is.  Is there a way I can just remove it?

Comment: Most people here are misinterpreting the error message. It does not originate from AutoIt, but a from an AutoIt script that was compiled to a self-contained executable. It indicates the poorly written malware is malfunctioning.

Comment: @DanielB – exactly. And in this case, OP has no idea what AutoIt even is and has nothing against its uninstallation. AutoIt on his machine has no installer – all traces lead to malware.

Comment: identify the process at task manager and ensure its not listed under startup process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no idea what AutoIt even is. Is there a way I can just remove it?

Based on your comments, simply **uninstall AutoIt tool**. Use standard uninstaller in *Programs and Features* control panel.

AutoIt is great helper tool, but [cases were seen where macros hosted by AutoIt were actually malware](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/autoit-used-to-spread-malware-and-toolsets/). Therefore after uninstalling AutoIt, check your computer for malware/viruses and avoid [possible sources of malware](http://www.malwareteks.com/articles/MalwareSources.php).

---

Removal: (incomplete, waiting for your feedback)

1. [Create system restore point](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+system+restore+point). This allows you to restore your system to time of restore point creation whenever you want.
2. Verify if you have AutoIt files located in `C:\Program Files\AutoIt3`. Let me know the result in comments. As next step, we'll have to

   - run [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and find entries related to rFWaBL.exe or to AutoIt. (1) note their full file path, (2) uncheck them and (3) reboot.

Let me know the status.

Comment: I went to uninstall AutoIT today, but it's not showing up in the list of programs to remove? is there another way to uninstall it?

Comment: i am the only user on the computer

Comment: @user176105 – That's bad because normally, AutoIt has its uninstaller like other software. This looks like it was added by some sneaky way, like through some malware. I can help you with removal if you think you can (1) delete some program files (2) delete some entries in Registry database. It can take some 20-30 minutes.

Comment: thanks.  could you help me do those steps?  i had a feeling it was something like a virus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29104/discussion-between-miroxlav-and-user176105).

Answer (score 0):

Run [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), use the crosshair from toolbar

[image: Process Explorer CrossHair]

and move it to the Error message. This will highlight the program which causes the error message. Now run [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and disable the automatic start of the application.

Comment: when i did that cmd.exe was the program responsible.  what should i do next?

Comment: See my edited question for a screenshot

Comment: you have to activate the commandline column in ProcessExplorer and detect this way where the file is stored that cmd runs.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently the upgrade to Windows 10 has broken some product installed on the
computer. I see here two questions : (1) Which product, and (2) Is it a legitimate
product or a virus.

The second question is motivated by the fact that the
message is produced by AutoIt which is not installed on your computer.
However, entire products can be written using the scripting language of
AutoIt and then compiled into .exe files for distribution,
so this can still be a legitimate product.

I propose doing the following tests :

1. [Boot Into Safe Mode](http://www.7tutorials.com/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10)
   Normally the error message should disappear.
   If it does not, then Windows itself is infected.
2. Execute the advice given by [magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/a/972675/8672) to find out which
   executable has issued this error message.
   Using its name and the name of its folder, one can find out which product
   it is.
3. If it is a legitimate product, uninstall it or find a newer version
   better adapted to Windows 10.
4. If it is not legitimate, you will find good advice in here :
   [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Post the information you find, if you wish us to have a look.

Comment: thanks.  can you check my updated question for a screenshot after i used process explorer.  there was no message found when i entered safe mode

Comment: This process is unknown - not a good sign - and having so many copies is even worse. Could you double-click on it and post screenshots of the "Image" and "Thread" tabs. I also suggest that you do a deep scan by your antivirus and by [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/).